# How can I replicate mixed dtype warning from pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have read that in pandas if a column has mixed dtyped elements then reading that would lead to `DtypeWarning: Columns (X,X) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False in Pandas`

So, i am trying to replicate this error but i cant seem to do it. Below is the codebit that i am using to achieve the said behavior:

```
dfs=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c',1.,2.,np.nan],'b':['d','e','f','g','h',np.nan]})
dfs = pd.concat([dfs for i in range(10000)],axis=0)
dfs.to_csv('test_csv.csv',index=False)
pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv')
```

This leads to no warnings and just reads the data as object types. Can you please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`pandas.errors.DtypeWarning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.DtypeWarning.html):

> This warning is issued when dealing with larger files because the dtype checking happens per chunk read.

This is not crystal clear, but I think the reason you're **not** getting the warning is that you have different types within each chunk of data read, so `read_csv` automatically converts them to `object`.

When I create a dataframe with different types spread out in different chunks (i.e., long chunks of the same data type before switching to a different type), I get the warning.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ([1.] * 100000 + ['a'] * 100000 + [np.nan] * 100000),
                   'b': ([1.] * 100000 + ['b'] * 100000 + [np.nan] * 100000)})

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Output:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```